# Play framework Publish–subscribe pattern

Tags: meteor, playframework, publish-subscribe

Is there some utility library or like available to refresh webpage when content in database changed? E.g. I've external process which updates database, how to show changes somewhat automatically for end user? Other than some timer based "refresh web page every 1 minute".

I know only one web framework where this is available, [Meteor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteor_(web_framework))

[Publish-subscribe pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern)

Comment: What you're looking for is websockets https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaWebSockets

Comment: @RobertUdah Thank you. I suppose developer has to do hard work here so this kind of functionality is not in Play framework's DNA.